# merge error (not able to insert the values)

Tags: sql, oracle

Friends i am using merge syntax to update and insert values in a table

```
MERGE INTO iq_dnr b
   USING (SELECT *
            FROM iq_dnr
           WHERE co_series = 'IO' AND CATEGORY = 9 AND dnr_from = 13567362) a
   ON (    a.co_series = b.co_series
       AND a.CATEGORY = b.CATEGORY
       AND a.dnr_from = b.dnr_from)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE
         SET b.dnr_to = 0001
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (co_series, CATEGORY, dnr_from, dnr_to)
      VALUES ('IO', 9, 13567362, 00001)
```

and i want to ask whether it is possible to check and insert in one table only like i did in above query.
know the problem is i am able to successfully update the table but i am not able to insert the values .
plss help me

Comment: *‘i am not able to insert the values’* – how does that manifest itself? Are you getting error messages?

Comment: @AndriyM i am not getting any error but at toad it is displaying      0 row merge and i am not insert the values mean it is successfully updating the values but when i delete those values from table then values are not able to insert .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with using DUAL, it might solve your problem:

```
MERGE INTO iq_dnr b
   USING (SELECT 'IO' co_series,
                  9 CATEGORY,
                  13567362 dnr_from
            FROM dual) a
   ON (    a.co_series = b.co_series
       AND a.CATEGORY = b.CATEGORY
       AND a.dnr_from = b.dnr_from)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN
      UPDATE
         SET b.dnr_to = 0001
   WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (co_series, CATEGORY, dnr_from, dnr_to)
      VALUES ('IO', 9, 13567362, 00001)
```

Using above `DUAL` ensures that it returns something anyway which keeps MERGE statement working....

Comment: i had tried that also but still not able to insert the values

Comment: which oracle version are you using?

Comment: BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.1.0.7.0 - Production
CORE    11.1.0.7.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.1.0.7.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.1.0.7.0 - Production

Comment: @GirishRAcharya: I have updated my answer with using DUAL.....Check out with that one....

Comment: it is possible without using dual .

Comment: When you are merging with same table, if the second query table returns the empty set , the merge statement has no operation......So, it's better to use DUAL if u have to make merge with self....